# Why ClientRequest.* and storage.* metrics are not reported with builtin ConsoleReporter in DSE Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, codahale-metrics

I am trying to get the metrics from DSE Cassandra(dse: 5.1.0, Cassandra :3.10.0.1652) using builtin reporters like ConsoleReporter. I could able to get all the metrics except the metrics under ClientRequest.* and Storage.* even though I have reads/writes to this cluster . The only metric under ClientRequest.* group is `org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ClientRequest.ViewPendingMutations.ViewWrite`

I tried with different  reporter config, but no luck and I didn't find any JIRA associated to this as well. The same behavior with StatsD Reporter as well.

Here is the reporter config with wildcard whitelist

console:
  -

> outfile: '/tmp/metrics.out'
>       period: 10
>       timeunit: 'SECONDS'
>       predicate:
>         color: "white"
>         useQualifiedName: true
>         patterns:
>           - ".*"

Both the ClientRequest and Storage metrics are critical for me . Is any body has any pointers why I am not getting these metrics? I appreciate any insights on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some  issue with DSE version of Cassandra.Not sure something broken in latest version of DSE/Cassandra . I tested with Open Source Cassandra: 3.9.0 and it seems this works. I could able to get all the metrics under ClientRequest.* and Storage.* with the Open Source Cassandra 3.9.0.

Comment: DSE team confirmed this is bug in 5.1.* version.